# Python UI - Customizing

Tags: python, user-interface

I would prefer Tkinter, but what is the best UI library that can easily do the following:

*Transparent means see through the entire window*

- Transparent Background
- No border
- Transparent background of a text box (with a scroll bar), but still display text
- Change the look of the scroll bar
- Change the look of an entry box

Is all of this possible in a python library? I am using windows 7, and python 2.7 (if the library is in 3, then I will code it in 3).

Can you please also provide links/examples displaying how to do it in the library?

Comment: [Looks like wxPython can do it](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Transparent%20Frames)

Comment: The problem with that is that I can't display anything on it

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean.  Does my answer help at all?

Answer (score 3):

Tkinter is pretty limited when it comes to aesthetics but it definitely gets the job done

you could try [pythonwx](http://www.wxpython.org/) which is a bit more aesthetically pleasing and can do a bit more than Tk can **Edit:** looks like wx can make a transparent window

if by transparent you mean you can see what's in back of the window that maybe hard to do with any python library

although most people dont think of pygame as a library for User-Interface but ive used it to built pretty nice looking GUI like this weather app! it looks really good but since pygame isnt made to build gui's its a bit more complicated and takes alot more code

[image: Weather App]

you should also take a look at [Pyside](http://qt-project.org/wiki/PySide) i haven't used it but i hear its pretty good
also take a look at [pyGTK](http://www.pygtk.org/)

Im not sure if these suggestions can do all that you ask but look into all of them and then decide

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, by transparent I mean see what is behind the window

Comment: hmmm that could be very hard to do with python but you should look at all these not sure if any can do that though

Comment: well if you look at cody's link it looks like pythonwx can indeed make a transparent window

Comment: Thanks for pointing out it was a link! I was stupid and didn't notice!

Comment: yeah so i would use wx probably the best way good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the transparency of a frame using [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/).  You just have to use the `wx.Frame.SetTransparent()` method, which takes an argument from 0 (completely transparent) to 255 (completely opaque).

You can get wxPython for Python 2.7 [here](http://wxpython.org/download.php), or you can get a build for Python 3.x [here](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/snapshot-builds/).

Here is a code snippet and a screenshot to see what a frame containing a textbox, label, and button looks like with alpha set to 200, in front of my text editor with some text in it.

```
import wx

class TransparentFrame(wx.Frame):
    ''' Transparent Frame '''
    DEFAULT_ALPHA = 200
    DEFAULT_SIZE = (400, 200)
    TEXTCTRL_SIZE = (200, 100)
    def __init__(self, size=DEFAULT_SIZE, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, size=size, title='This is my title', *args, **kwargs)
        # This is all you need to make the window transparent.
        self.SetTransparent(self.DEFAULT_ALPHA)

        label = wx.StaticText(self, label= 'Here is a label:  ')

        text = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE, size=self.TEXTCTRL_SIZE)
        text.WriteText('Fill the box with text!\n' * 10)

        button = wx.Button(self, label='This is a button')

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.AddMany([label, text, button])
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = TransparentFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image: Transparent frame over my text editor]

Comment: I can make a window transparent, but I needed the labels, textctrls and buttons to have 100% opacity.